# Can't get if statement to work

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class stringComparer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter 1 word here - ");
        String word1 = scan.next();

    System.out.println ("Enter another word here - ");
    String word2 = scan.next();

    if (word1 == word2) {
        System.out.println("They are the same");
    }
}
}
```

I had it working about 10 minutes ago, changed something and it now it doesn't display "They are the same" for some reason? Its really simple yet I can't see where I've gone wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator compares objects *by reference*.

To find out whether two different `String` instances hold the same value, call `.equals()`.

Therefore, replace

```
if (word1 == word2)
```

with

```
if (word1.equals(word2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this  it will work, `String is not primitive` so when u check `==` it will check the references .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * This program compares two strings
 * @author Andrew Gault
 * @version 28.10.2012
 */
 public class stringComparer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter 1 word here - ");
        String word1 = scan.next();

    System.out.println ("Enter another word here - ");
    String word2 = scan.next();

    if (word1.equals(word2))
    {
        System.out.println("They are the same");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (word1.equals(word2))
{
 System.out.println("They are the same");   
}
```

See why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)